# Getting Specific columns from csv which contains empty cells in between

Tags: mapreduce

I am trying to parse specific columns from a csv using map reduce.I have some empty cells in my csv. When I am trying to run it shows some exceptions.But When i run a csv which has no empty cells I get my output.

```
sss     xx     asdas    sddf
saq            asdsds   sdsds
ewe     zz     asdsd    
aaa     qq     adsd     ssdds
```

my csv looks like that and my mapper output must be like this

```
sss  xx  sddf   1
saq      sdsds  1 
ewe  zz         1
aaa  qq  ssdds  1
```

My Mapper Code is

```
public class DataMap extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper< 
LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable> {

public final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
        OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter r)
        throws IOException {

    String a = value.toString();

    String[] temp = a.split("\t");
    output.collect(new Text(temp[0] + "\t" +temp[1] + "\t" +temp[3]), new IntWritable(a));
    }
    }
```

How can i over come this.